# laravel removing CSRF token from specific route not working

Tags: laravel, csrf

So I am working with an API which after processing does a callback to my app which is written in Laravel 5, the API requires the callback to be a post method and that is exactly what my routes file say.

Routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'donate'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'paygateway'], function () {
        Route::post('success', 'Donate\PaygatewayController@succesfull');
    });

});
```

I have also added this in VerifyCsrfToken file in the except array

```
protected $except = [
        'donate/paygateway/success',
    ];
}
```

Somehow this still gives me TokenMismatchException when the API posts to it and I cannot seem to figure out how/why. I tried the full URL, with trailingslashes, without and middlewares in the controllers, no succes.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try `php artisan route:list` and double check the url and the attached middleware. Else just start making some debug statements in `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`

Comment: @Flame That doesn't seem to work aswell, it doesn't fire the Verification. I am completely lost as to why this is happening. When I use postman to post to that URI it works perfectly when I add the exception.

Comment: so Postman is doing something else than the API you compare it to? I would just start with setting some debug outputs in the class I gave you (or your own class if it extends that one), and see if its actually reaching that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php file in your Laravel project.
Add the route you want to exclude to the $except property:

```
protected $except = [
    'your-route-here',
];
```

The middleware may not be applied to the route you're trying to exclude. Check your app/Http/Kernel.php file to make sure the VerifyCsrfToken middleware is applied to the correct route(s).

try clearing your application's cache by running the php artisan cache:clear

/// config/cors.php

['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['env(APP_DOMAIN)', '*.env(APP_DOMAIN)'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

   

];

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue as well. When I ran the laravel app on localhost:8000, all was good. But when I ran app on just localhost (port 80), I got the csrf mismatch error anytime I sent a post request to the api. What I found was that changing the domain name from localhost to something else made the error to stop. It turned out that this was controlled by the `stateful` property in the /config/sanctum.php file. So if you have tried the standard remedies and they don't work, edit that file and remove localhost from the stateful domains. Or set  SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="anything_other_than_localhost" environment variable. Then clear cache: `php artisan config:clear` and try again.